# Export a Flex graph to excel

Tags: apache-flex, excel, charts, export

Is there a way to export a flex graph to excel?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While I've never tried doing this myself, it looks like some other folks have solutions for exporting to Excel.

Check out:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/11/open-in-excel-another-air-2-mini-sample/
http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Mine is not an AIR application.  I have used as3xls to export a table/datagrid but could not export a flex chart.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following might help if you are using a Flex app served from a Web app with a Java backend.

Flex includes some nifty out-of-the-box functionality for capturing images.  If it suits your requirements to simply take a snapshot of the graph and slap it into an Excel document, it should be possible.

[Here's an example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/16/taking-screenshots-in-flex-using-the-imagesnapshotcaptureimage-method/) for grabbing a snapshot.  The bytes could conceivably be streamed back to the Web app.  Then you could reconvert the bytes into an image object and use [POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images) to add the image to Excel.

Another option might be to take the same underlying dataset used for rendering the chart in Flex and just build the chart in Excel.  That assumes that the chart does not need to have the same look and feel as the corresponding Flex version, though.  I've never used it, but [the jXLS tool](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/chartsample.html) looks like it might provide Excel chart-building capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did try to capture the image from Flex app.  However, I am not able to export the captured image to excel. I dont think jXLS tool is right for me.  I will explore on that though.  Thank you.